# How to debug Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I am working on a Chef recipe and now I would like to know how debugging of recipes can be done. This seems to be not all straightforward.

For example adding simple log statements is unclear. I can use for example

```
     Chef::Log.info "My message"
```

But it is unclear where this message will be logged. It doesn't appear in the chef client run console even with verbose output for example as follows

```
     knife ssh mynode "sudo chef-client" --manual-list --ssh-user myuser -VV
```

The best/most advanced way I found so far for debugging to just raise an exception. Not at all advanced.

Answer (score 6):

Here you're setting `knife` command as verbose with `-VV`.

To change `chef-client` run log level the parameter is `-l info` or `-l debug` for its command call.

In your command line it would give (info level, debug is really verbose, and you're loggin at info level in your recipe):

```
knife ssh mynode "sudo chef-client -l info" --manual-list --ssh-user myuser -VV
```